# Let User Create Objects On Runtime (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, class, object

I've had many help from this forum, but this time I can't find an answer to my question on this forum, so I will ask it here. I hope you guys can help me and that this topic is useful for others around here.

I started programming some months ago, (I want to make it my job, next year I will go to college were I will learn it, this is just for myself now.) and I really like it.

I am reading the book "Programming In Objective-C (Fourth Edition)" from Steve Kochan. I didn't finish it yet, but it's a good book for the real beginners in programming.

Now I started programming some Apps for myself. In this case it's an order-tracking App. The user can press the + or - button to increase the quantity he has to order. I added 4 products myself (objects from the "Product"-Class), but I want to give the user of the App the ability to add custom products himself.
Here is the code: (it's really simple, but I am just messing around a little bit)

Product.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Product : NSObject
{
    unsigned int valueOfProducts;
}

-(void) increaseValueOfProducts;
-(void) decreaseValueOfProducts;
-(void) resetValueOfProducts;

@end
```

Product.m:

```
#import "Product.h"

@implementation Product

-(void) increaseValueOfProducts {
    valueOfProducts += 1;
}

-(void) decreaseValueOfProducts {

    if ( valueOfProducts > 0 ) {
        valueOfProducts -= 1;
    }
}

-(void) resetValueOfProducts {
    valueOfProducts = 0;
}

@end
```

main.m:

```
#import "Product.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        Product *sandwich = [[Product alloc] init];
        Product *coke = [[Product alloc] init];
        Product *chips = [[Product alloc] init];
        Product *bread = [[Product alloc] init];

    }
}
```

Now is my question: *Is there any method, or something, that I can add so the user can add objects (so, new products) to the program he wants to keep track of?*

I don't remember I have had that in the book, and I don't know what to search for. So I hope someone can help me with this.

Many thanks to anyone responding!

PS: Hope I added the code in this post on the right way.

Comment: To your PS: the tag `xcode` is not right - this is not a question about Xcode, rather about Objective-C.

Comment: Also, it's important (not quite clear to me): in what sense do you want to "add objects"? If you simply create some kind of user input (text, numbers, whatever), then a button for which the action method allocates a new object with the attributes the user entered, it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Sorry, I will keep that in mind for any other questions!

Comment: You're right. I want to make a GUI for it. It will look like this: http://d.pr/i/reOf (Ignore the "Labels", there will come the value for the products.) What I mean is that when the user presses the + button (right top) that there will come a new product.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at `UITableView`. If you create a new project using the "Master-Detail Application" template you will have something to start with (including a "+" button !)

Comment: @userXXX Have a look at the `addSubview:` method of `UIView`.

Comment: @MartinR and H2CO3 I'm sorry, but I am not that far in programming. I never made a GUI (that subject is at the end of my book). I thought there might be something I could do with code that I could link to the GUI-elements in Xcode. Maybe, if there is no solution in the actual code, I should read on to the end of the book and then try it again?

Comment: Sounds like you should move on to a book that covers UI....

Comment: That would be the best option I guess. I really thought it was in the code; when I add a new "product" through the UI, how could the program ever keep track of the value since it's not in the code? I'm sorry if I'm unclear in my question.

Comment: Usually you read the values in the UI elements and set them on an instance of the Product class. Example: `Product *p = [Product new]; p.name = <NAME-READ-FROM-THE-UI>;` (for this example to work, you would also need to create a name variable or whatever properties you want to let your user set).

Comment: Thanks! But there can never be multiply "p-objects", right? Or can I do something like Product *p.name = [Product new]; where p.name is a variable which the user entered? (How do I set code tags here, like in the Opening Post?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really go from non-UI, command line, programming to UI programming and expect things to work at all the same.

If you want user input, you will need a text field on screen that the user enters stuff into and then some means of submitting the text into the program such that it updates your Product instance;  a button, the return key, something.

This will require a basic understanding of how applications are structured, how to load or dynamically create a user interface, how to process user input, how to connect your UI to your data storage classes/instances, etc...

It really sounds like you need to move on from the Kochan book -- which seems to be more focused on language level stuff and less on building real world apps? -- and use tutorials that teach you how to build GUI apps.

Apple provides a ton of [getting started guides](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Getting%20Started)...

Comment: Thanks. I think that's the best option. But I am interested in the language too, so I will finish this book and then grab a book that covers how to build Apps. I totally underestimated it. Everyone thanks for helping me!